# How can I get an alert if my application is down?

Tags: windows-xp, uptime, runtime

Is there a WinXP application/service that will monitor other applications for runtime?

I've seen the [MS uptime monitor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q232243/), but that just seems to be for server uptime, not for individual apps.

Haven't found anything searching in here, either. If this is a dupe, am I using the wrong search terms?

UPDATE (years later): to answer a comment, I define down as "not running", so.. no PID I suppose. This question was written for a former job, so I don't have personal need of it anymore. Monitoring services, as answered below, seems like the best solution. At the time, none of the apps in question were written as services. Tsk tsk tsk!

Comment: How do you define down?  Do you mean in the task list but not using %cpu or do you mean not in the task list?  Are you talking about Apps that you can change or Apps where you cannot rebuild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal solution to this kind of problem is to use some kind of [server/network monitoring software.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_monitoring)

That is basically a dedicated service running on a server, which will monitor multiple machines (and the S/W on them) via the network. They can also detect whether individual services are up.

See e.g.

https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

https://serverfault.com/questions/1596/application-monitoring-tools

https://serverfault.com/questions/26685/server-monitoring

I have personally used ZenOSS, which can do monitor applications and send alerts, produce graphs etc..

Using a monitoring software for a single app might be overkill, but OTOH it's a standard solution, and most monitoring software is reasonably simple to set up for simple cases, and can run on the monitored machine, so it might be the best solution.

I am not aware of any app just for checking the status of a single, local application.

Comment: It's not for a single app, or on a local machine. I wasn't sure of the correct terminology, and I was posting this before our Network guys had even begun to think about coffee.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope your problem may be fixed with this: 
http://total-network-monitor.en.softonic.com/

In our organization we are monitoring all the services and systems by assigning with Alerts and Mails.

Comment: Please write what is behind the link. The link can stop functioning in the future.